# Migrating a Service Fabric app to Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-service-fabric

I currently have a service fabric app consisting of 2 [Asp.Net core WebApi-based stateless services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-create-dotnet-app) using CosmosDb as backend storage. It is about basic CRUD operations against a document database.

Since I know that this app will evolve into even more services, and probably additional direct service-to-service communication, I wonder if migrating to a [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview) based solution makes sense. 
Or will this force me into a corner where I eventually find out that Azure Functions are pretty limited, and designed for very different use cases.

Is it reasonable to expect that I can migrate my asp.net core services into Azure Functions with just minor code changes to the services, or do I need to consider a complete redesign to adjust for a different programming model?

And since [Service Fabric Mesh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric-mesh/service-fabric-mesh-overview) is now in public preview and then GA sometime (hopefully) soon, will that be a better solution for me? The migration path from sf to sf mesh is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You will have varying degrees of effort migrating your existing asp.net api apps to Azure Functions.  Having migrated several asp.net API projects to Azure Functions I found the best success with projects whose core logic was implemented in a separate layer. If your Web API makes heavy use of middleware layers, dependency injection, or makes a lot of use of attribute based filters then you have some work ahead of you as those don't translate directly in azure functions. Complex authentication and authorization scenarios typically provided by middle layers were often a challenge as well. There are a few community projects that offer up ways to host asp.net APIs in functions but I don't have any experience with them and they are of course unsupported by MS.

In regards to the "should I" portion of the question I think you have to look at the benefits that Azure Functions provides (micro-billing\scaling\devops\etc) and measure that against the cost of migrating you're code to the platform and potential feature loss. I am a big proponent of Azure Functions but I would not consider migrating from such a capable platform as Service Fabric, which is actually ideal for micro-services, without making that type of assessment.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you consider moving towards Azure Functions?

If you expect a grow in service-to-service communication, I doubt you should move from service fabric to Azure Function. So without knowing your application I belive you won't benefit moving towards Azure Function unless you maybe have a full event based application and using Azure Function may reduce your Azure costs.

To answer your question, you can probably reuse most of your code but you have to reimplement the hosting / deployment and communication between services.